# Printing last 3 lines of a .csv file

Tags: python-3.x, csv

Need to get this section of python to print out individual lines found at the end of a .csv file in a human readable format. The information of a whole line needs to be printed on its own line.

I have tried using "deque" and it produces tons of useless characters brackets, and information not needed. It is difficult to read whenever I used the deque.
I have gotten it to print the very last line, but I can not get the 2 more from before it.

```
#This section is intented to test the code that would print the last 3 entries to the INV.csv.
#Code currently not working.
def EX1():
    #Tells the user what they are seeing.
    print("====-----EXPERIMENTAL SECTION-----====")
    print("This section tests the call back method for last 3 vehichles added to inventory.")
    print("")

    with open('INV.csv','r') as INQB: #Opens INV.csv as read only.
        lineA = INQB.readline()[-1] #Works just fine, as intended.
        lineB = INQB.readline()[-2] #Does not work.
        #lineC = INQB.readline()[-3] #Still doesn't work.

        print("Previously listed entries to the Inventory List are as follows:") #To tell user what they are reading.

        #Need these print commands to print 3rd 2nd and last entry line made to INV.csv.
        #These entries are msade by another defined area not shown here.
        #print(lineC)
        print(lineB)
        print(lineA)

        #This is to tell me that this area was reached when tested and didnt fail.
        print("Stuff was supposed to be there /\.")            
        print("") #Spacing for readability.

        INQB.close() #Closes it (If its not closed it gets crashy)
        starter() #Exits to other portions of the program.
```

I need this patch of the code to produce the last 3 lines of the .csv in a human readable format.

- Third to last line in the .csv
- Second to last line in the .csv
- Very last line in the .csv

Answer (score 2):

Read all the lines, then print the last three:

```
with open('INV.csv') as INQB:
    lines = INQB.readlines()  # Reads all lines into a list.

for line in lines[-3:]:  # slices the list for the last three entries.
    print(line,end='') # end='' because the lines already have newlines in them.
```

If the file is too huge to read all lines, you can seek back from the end an amount larger than 3 maximum length lines.  For example:

```
# Create a file with 100 lines in it to use for demonstration.
with open('INV.csv','w') as f:
    for line in range(100):
        f.write(f'line {line}\n')

# Now open the file and read three lines efficiently.
with open('INV.csv','rb') as f: # open in binary for seek operations
    # Lines created above were 10 bytes long max, go back more than 3x that
    f.seek(-50,2) # 2 means end-of-file
    lines = f.readlines()  # read only the last few lines of the file

for line in lines[-3:]:  # slice only the last three lines and display.
    print(line.decode(),end='') # decode the line to text since file was opened in binary.
```

Output:

```
line 97
line 98
line 99
```

Comment: First section offered that reads the entire file returns the number "7". The second block of code in your suggestion prints only "line 97" there are currently 15 lines of information in the .csv. Correction. it overwrote the entire .csv and only returned what is now line 97. I need it to print the last 3 rows that were written to the .csv file.

Comment: @BrandonToolbelt Without seeing what you did to get those results, I can't help you.  The first section above reads all the lines from a file into a list, then prints the last three lines.  I don't know what is in your file.  The second example is a standalone example that *creates* a file with 100 lines, then prints the last three.  It works as is.  If you made changes, You'll have to update your question with the attempt and actually show some part of the file you are using, or ask a new question.  I'll add some comments to the code for clarity.